# Firestore security rule: query subcollection based on permission of parent document

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's say I have a `restaurants` collection with `menus` subcollection. The restaurant permission is set inside the restaurant document and it looks like this:

**Restaurant**

```
{
 "roles": {
    "user123": "Owner"
  }
}
```

Anyone who has access to the restaurant also has access to any of its subcollections, including the `menus` subcollection. Here is the security rule for this:

**Security Rule**

```
match /restaurants/{restaurantId}/{document=**} {
  allow read: if resource.data.roles[request.auth.uid] > '' ;
}
```

Querying for the list of restaurants can be accomplished like this and it works well:

**Query for restaurants**

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('restaurants')
      .where(`roles.${uid}`, '>', '');
```

Now how do I query the `menus` subcollection? I understand that Firestore needs to infer the permission based on the query without looking at the underlying data. Logically this should be possible, as anyone who has access to the `restaurant` also has access to the `menus` subcollection. But how do I compose this `menus` subcollection query so that Firestore can infer this? The most logical query I can come up with is something like this:

**Query for menus subcollection (doesn't work)**

```
firebase
     .firestore()
     .doc(`restaurants/${restaurantId}`) // user has access to this restaurant
     .collection('menus');
```

...but that doesn't work with permission being denied.

Comment: The `=**` in your `match /restaurants/{restaurantId}/{document=**}` means that the rule applies to the restaurant doc and everything under that. But do those menus meet this requirement: `resource.data.roles[request.auth.uid] > ''`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen oh that's a very good point. There is no `roles` in menus, so that's probably the problem. I initially tried this: `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/restaurants/$(restaurantId)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] > ''`, but it doesn't look like `get` and `exists` is allowed for list queries. Do you know how I can make this work?

Comment: I don't mind creating another rule for `menus` subcollection if I need to, but even then, I'm not sure how I can get Firestore to infer access to `menus` based on the the `roles` in the parent `restaurant`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it turns out that I need to create 2 security rules at the `restaurant` level to achieve what I want:

```
    match /restaurants/{restaurantId} {
      allow read: if resource.data.roles[request.auth.uid] > ''
    }

    match /restaurant/{restaurantId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/restaurants/$(restaurantId)).data.roles[request.auth.uid] > '';
    }
```

The first rule is necessary in order to query for restaurants that the user has permission to. The second query alone won't work, although I'm not sure why. This is the query for the first rule:

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('restaurants')
      .where(`roles.${uid}`, '>', '');
```

The second rule is necessary for all subcollection queries. Here's an example:

```
firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`restaurants/${restaurantId}/menus`);
```

The fact that the second rule allows the subcollection query is very interesting, as Firestore needs to read the `restaurant` document in order to permit this query. This contradicts its claims that it doesn't look at the underlying data for queries, but it looks like it does if it needs to read just one document within a path.

Comment: Good to hear you got it working!    I'm never sure how smart the rules engine is. As in: I've been surprised about it in the past. Here I could imagine that it is actually able to prove that your condition on the subcollection is always true for your condition on the parent document.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen true, but am I correct to conclude that Firestore had to look at the restaurant data in order to permit the subcollection query? I find this quite fascinating because it does explain a lot about how these rules work.

Comment: You can't query on conditional rules. ie: using rules to filter documents from the collection. as Firebase Team says "Rules are a bouncer, not a Firewall" as for your later rules, this should work. since the roles are global to that sub-collection.

Comment: @JohnnyOshika I'm not sure if it has to do that, but you could try by only reading the subcollection without ever reading the parent doc. Even if it does, that might still be in line with the guidance as it doesn't have to inspect *every* document to check whether it meets the criteria, it just has to check the (single) parent document. If that is indeed what happens here, you could for example not use the same rules to allow a collection *group* query, as that'd mean the rules engine would have to look at many documents - including ones that don't exist yet.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In fact, if you look at my subcollection query example in my answer above, I'm not reading the parent doc, so Firestore must be reading the parent doc to check permission on the subcollection. Good point about this still being consistent with Firestore not having to inspect every document. As for the collection group query, that's an interesting question. I wonder if it will be allowed with the already defined rules, as the rules engine would need to inspect many parent docs.

Comment: Based on that last line, I doubt it'll be allowed. The key consideration is: can this rule be enforced when the listener connects. If not, there's no chance that it's allowed. If it can be, then I by now have faith that the engineers have at least tried to make it work.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: For anyone who's interested in related but more advanced security rules for Firestore, check out this community talk by Michael Dowden: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyZQBC-KSuM