# Firestore Security Rules for a Subcollection not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a collection for messaging, called `channels` with a subcollection called `thread`:

`channels` > `docID` > `thread` > `threadID`

### **EDIT #1** (added database screen shot)

[image]
[image]

In each channel doc, I have an array `members` which holds the userIDs of the members of the channel.

Based on the Firebase docs and some other Stackoverflow posts, I have my rules as follows:

```js
match /channels/{channelId} {
   function isSignedIn() {
     return request.auth.uid != null;
   }
    function isMember() {
      return request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }

    // allow user to create new channel if they are registered
  allow create: if isSignedIn();

    // allow read, update, delete only if user is in the channel
  allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isMember(); 

  match /thread/{threadId} {

    // allow new thread creation if user is registered
    allow create: if isSignedIn();

    // only allow reading, updating, and deleting if they are 
    // registered and a member of the thread
    allow update, read, delete: if isSignedIn() && isMember(); 
  }
}
```

I'm using a listener to detect changes in the channel, and I was able to receive real-time updates before I changed my security rules. Now, when I post in a chat message using `isMember()` requirement, I do not receive any errors, but the thread doesn't update with new messages. If I navigate away from the chat, then back to it, I can see the new messages. If I disable the `isMember()` requirement, or change the `isMember` function to something like `is request.auth.uid == [a specific userID I know is in the thread]` it works as expected, with the thread updating with new messages at real-time (without having to navigate away from the screen).

### **Edit #2** (temporary solution)

Based on [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220310/firestore-security-rule-query-subcollection-based-on-permission-of-parent-docum), I have it working with these rules. However, I'm still confused as to why it wasn't working before, and I'd like to know if there's an alternative to this solution that doesn't require an additional document read (via the get request). It seems like the `members` field would be able to be accessed either through the parent doc, or within the thread itself (as I've duplicated it for this reason) and compared against `request.auth.uid`.

```
    match /channels/{channelId} {
        function isMember() {
          return request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
        }
        // allow user to create new channel if they are registered
        allow create: if isSignedIn();
        // allow read, write, update, delete only if user is in the channel
        allow read, update, delete: if isSignedIn() && isMember();
    }
    
    match /channels/{channelId}/{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/channels/$(channelId)).data.members;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Done, thanks for looking into it

Comment: I have one security rule in mine that also uses an "in" statement. It has been a while since I worked on it, but I remember spending a lot of time testing it and being surprised that the only way I could get it to work was with an additional document read via get, similar to your temporary solution.

Comment: Some questions (not sure if these are answers, but will ask in case they are helpful):
1. Did you try passing the resource.data.members array into the isMembers function to make sure it can see it?
2. Are you certain the members array on the thread document is always the same as the channel document and always contains all members? I noticed in your temporary solution which you said is working, you are getting members from the channel doc, not the thread doc. That could be a material difference, maybe.

Comment: @most200 I tried your suggestion, and unfortunately, it didn't work. Yes, the members array is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing updates to clients whenever new messages are added to a thread using Cloud Functions and Firestore's built-in support for real-time updates. As a result, there would be no need for the client to re-query the data whenever a new message is added, and updates should surface in real-time with no additional client work.

In essence, you can use Cloud Functions to watch for modifications to the Firestore collection or document and run some server-side logic each time a new message is added to the thread collection. In order to push the update to the client in real-time, the server-side code can then use a service like Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM).

References:

- [Firestore Realtime Updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)
- [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)
- [Firestore Triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear before, but I am using a listener to detect for changes to the channel and it was working before I implemented the new security rules. I added more info to the post for clarity.